# jQtouch toggal checkbox change default position to On

Tags: jqtouch

I am using jQtouch for my iPhone application,

I need to check box filed, in jQtouch we have the code below like this.

```
<ul>
    <li> 
      Toggle The <span class="toggle"><input type="checkbox"/></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

By using this code we can display the 
On-Off image, in the it will be by default off position.

But I need the 'On' position by default.

can you some one help me out for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is to add  "checked" to the `<input>` tag:

```
Toggle The <span class="toggle"><input type="checkbox" checked/></span>
```

IF you want to handle programmaticaly:

```
$('toggle input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', true)
```

If you put that in your .Ready() (or page loaded function) the checkbox will be checked by default.

I would recommend that you give the Checkbox an id so that you can specify exactly which you want to change:

```
<ul>
    <li> 
      Toggle The <span class="toggle"><input id="myCheckbox" type="checkbox"/></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then use:

```
$('#myCheckbox').attr('checked', true)
```